# Power Bi measures in a matrix

Tags: matrix, powerbi

I am a student currently doing a work placement. I have been tasked with creating a visual based on the clients needs they would like this to be in the form of a matrix. I have been able to create the measures required to achieve this but am currently struggling with being able to visualise it the way they have asked.

Field List:

[image]

Calculated columns :

[image]

[image]

Measures:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is an example of a chart I already have which shows the average score for each subject across all schools.

[image]

Below are the tables I have for my dataset:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Below is an example of how they would like the outcome to be presented which I am struggling with:

[image]

Comment: I can't tell what your specific question is. Posts on Stack Overflow are expected to be specific rather than a requirement demand.

Comment: I'd appreciate an answer to this question as I need a solution to a problem similar to this question. TIA!